# Angular momentum problem

Tags: physics

[image]

For a, I did:

$width = 4m$ ; $F = 19 N$ ;$ work = 205 rev/min$ or $3.42 rev/sec$.

Then, $m=F/g = 19/9.8m/s^2 = 1.94 kg$

Then, $a = 1/12mr^2$

Then $1/12 (1.94 kg)(4m^2)$

So, $I = 2.6 kgm^2$

For b, I did:

momentum = Iw

= 2.6kgm^2 * 3.42 rev/s = 56kg/m^2/s

Are those right?

Comment: I can't get the image embedded. How do I do tat?

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be a rod of length $L$ and radius $r_1$. The rod is rotating about one end, the moment of inertia is given by the definition:

$$I=\iiint_{E} r^2 dm$$

Where $r$ is the distance from the axis of rotation, and $m$ is referring to mass. But assuming constant density, density is  $\frac{dm}{dV}=\delta=\text{const}$ and so $dm=\delta dV$ so we have,

$$I=\iiint_{E} r^2 \delta dV$$

$$=\delta \iiint_{E} r^2 dV$$

Let the rod be around the $z$ axis and start at $z=0$ then to $z=L$, define the $z=0$ end to be the one we are rotating about. Then we have:

$$I=\delta \iiint_{E} z^2 dV$$

Now we switch to polar, do not confuse the $r$ here below to the previous $r$ in the formula for moment of inertia.

$$=\delta \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{r_1} \int_{0}^{L}  r z^2 dz dr d\theta$$

$$=(\delta)(2\pi)(\frac{r_1^2}{2})(\frac{L^3}{3})$$

$$=\frac{\delta (\pi r_1^2 L)}{3}L^2$$

$$=\frac{(\delta)(V(E))}{3}L^2$$

Here $V(E)$ denotes the volume of $E$ and note volume•density=mass for constant density.

$$=\frac{M}{3}L^2$$

This result does not agree with the formula you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the formula for rotational inertia of a thin rod rotating about an axis perpendicular to the rod *through the center of mass of the rod.*
But the rod in the question is rotating around an axis that passes across one end of the rod, not through the center.

In the formula for rotational momentum, $I\omega,$ the correct units for $\omega$ in this question would be radians per second, not revolutions per second.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for moment of inertia you're using is wrong.

The moment of inertia of a uniform rod about an axis through its centre is $I_1 = \frac{1}{12}ml^2$

whereas the moment of inertia of a uniform rod about an axis through one end is $I_2 = \frac{1}{3}ml^2$

You can work one out from the other by a trivial application of the parallel axis theorem.

In this case, you are to use the second formula. So $I = \frac 13 ml^2$.

Convert all values to SI units. Here $m = \frac Wg \approx \frac{19}{9.81} \approx 1.94 \mathrm{kg}$ So the moment of inertia is $\frac 13 (1.94)(4^2) = 10.33 \mathrm{kg.m^2}$ (to 3 significant figures, which is the expected level of precision).

You might get a slightly different answer depending on the value of $g$ you're given or supposed to take.

For the angular momentum, use $L = I\omega$ (note that large $L$ here is not length but angular momentum). Convert $\omega$ to SI units by finding $2\pi f$, where $f$ is the frequency of revolution in Hertz. So in this case, $\omega = 2\pi\frac{205}{60} \approx 21.5 \mathrm{rad/s}$. Hence the final answer is $10.33*21.5$ (taking more figures in the intermediate calculation), which should give you: $222 \mathrm{kgm^2/s}$